# Kiron lense on a Canon EOS camera

Tags: lens, adapter

I recently bought a Canon EOS 1300D to which I would like to fit a Kiron wide angle lens. The Kiron is a 24mm f/2 55mm lens diameter in the front, 45mm diameter at the back where it needs to be connected to the camera. At the back of the lens are 2 protruding small objects approximately 2-3mm sticking out. One is movable, and controls the aperture setting, one is not. Do you have an adapter that would make it possible to use this lense with my Canon camera?

Comment: It's unclear from the question: is the rear of the lens threaded or is there some type of bayonet mount there? Pictures of the front and back of the lens would be very helpful in identifying for what type of mount it is made. Kiron was a third party lens maker back in the day that made lenses in pretty much every imaginable mount in use at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Fotodiox (and probably others) have lens mount adapters for EF/EF-S to either Pentax K or M42 mounts. Not sure which one you have - the Kiron 24mm f/2 apparently came in two versions, one with the K mount and one with the M42.

Comment: Kiron offered a bunch of different mounts for most of the lenses they made back then. I've got one in the Konica AF mount. It's probably more accurate to say that there are versions of the Kiron 24mm f/2 in K-mount and M42 that have been offered on eBay at one time or another.

Comment: @MichaelClark Wasn't aware there were other mounts... Not surprised though. The info I got was from [here](https://www.pentaxforums.com/userreviews/kiron-24mm-f2.html), not eBay, though...

Comment: I'd guess the Pentax forum is only concerned with mounts used on old Pentax bodies? Do they list other mounts for any lens in that database?

Comment: This website: http://allphotolenses.com/lenses/item/c_1931.html  says this lens was made in the following mounts: C/Y (contax/yashica), Canon FD, FDn, Konica AR, M42, Nikon F (FX, DX), Olympus OM, Pentax K, Minolta SR (MD, MC)